# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable; matplotlib figsize

Tags: matplotlib, figsize

```
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

...(Other code loading my data)...

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
```

My code throws an error. Any ideas?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-d717924e19f2> in <module>()
      1 #visualize
----> 2 plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
      3 plt.title('Close Price History')
      4 plt.plot(df['Close'])
      5 plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please show the full error with traceback.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the line `plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))`. Perhaps try restarting your python kernel and run it again. Is it possible you ended up reassigning `plt.figure` somewhere by mistake?

Comment: can you print(plt.figure)? My suspicion is in some part of your code, you accidentally wrote something like plt.figure = (16,8). Restarting the kernel/removing the offending line of code would probably fix the issue, in that case.